# Amazon Auto-Scalling for heavy loop

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, autoscaling

We have a NodeJS App that runs a loop for analysing some data from json files, in some cases the loop will iterate over 100 milion times and sometimes fails

Our NodeJS app runs on t2.micro and I attached it to Auto-scalling group and set the min to 1 and max to 10.
When the CPU hitted 85%, the Auto-Scalling added 5 more instances and ended up running 10 instances at the end.

But the loop failed to complete running and has been interupted by the OS even with 10 instances (10 cores and 10GB RAM in total)

Does Auto Scalling doesn't spread the load on the CPU in this case? so it is more for Auto Scalling web application using load balancing?

I runned the same loop on my core i5 4 cores CPU and completed successfully

Answer (score 2):

That's not how autoscaling works. The loop runs on a single virtual machine just as it runs on your computer. The 9 instances that were started just sat there and did nothing while the loop continued to run on the first instance. Please read about [horizontally scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability#Horizontal_and_vertical_scaling) and [What is Auto Scaling?](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/WhatIsAutoScaling.html)